# Proof of a comparison inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

I'm working on a problem that's been giving me some difficulty. I will list it below and show what work I've done so far:

> If a, b, c, and d are all greater than zero and $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}$, prove that $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{a + c}{b + d} < \frac{c}{d}$.

Alright, so far I think the first step is to notice that $\frac{a}{b+d} + \frac{c}{b+d} < \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d}$ but after that I'm not sure how to continue. Any assistance would be a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First prove that
$$\dfrac{a}b < \dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$$
This can be done as follows.
$$\dfrac{a}b < \dfrac{c}d \implies ad < bc \implies ab + ad < ab + bc \implies a(b+d) < b(a+c) \implies \dfrac{a}b < \dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$$
Similarly, now prove that
$$\dfrac{a+c}{b+d} < \dfrac{c}d$$
This is done as follows.
$$\dfrac{a}b < \dfrac{c}d \implies ad < bc \implies ad + cd < bc + cd \implies (a+c)d < c(b+d) \implies \dfrac{a+c}{b+d} < \dfrac{c}d$$

Comment: Wow! Thank for the help, the method makes sense and is clear.

Answer (score 1):

As $$\frac ab<\frac cd\implies ad<bc\text { as } a,b,c,d>0$$

$$\frac{a+c}{b+d}-\frac ab=\frac{b(a+c)-a(b+d)}{b(b+d)}=\frac{bc-ad}{b(b+d)}>0 \text{ as } ad<bc \text{ and }  a,b,c,d>0 $$

So, $$\frac{a+c}{b+d}>\frac ab$$

Similarly,  $$\frac{a+c}{b+d}-\frac cd=\frac{ad-bc}{d(b+d)}<0\implies  \frac{a+c}{b+d}<\frac cd$$