# Prove when b > 0, d > 0, $ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d} $ follows $ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac{c}{d}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, field-theory, real-numbers

As the title already tells, I'm trying to prove the following claim:

When b > 0, d > 0, $ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d} $ follows $ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac{c}{d}$

My approach would be **to split up the proof** into 2 parts, with the **1st** proving that $ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{a+c}{b+d} $ is true and with the **2nd** proving that $ \frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac{c}{d} $

However I'm struggling to come any further than this.

**Important** to mention is also that this problem requires you to only use **field axioms**.

Comment: try cross-multiplying

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\frac{a}{b}&lt;\frac{a+c}{b+d}&lt;\frac{c}{d}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4276118/prove-fracab-fracacbd-fraccd)

Comment: or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246422/my-idea-is-to-consider-the-assumption-that-fracab-fraccd-and-perha)?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/205654/42969

Comment: Thanks to all of you for sharing those great answers.

Comment: The is the so-called “mediant inequality” and has been asked and answered many many times. You can find more identical questions [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%20%3C%20%5Cfrac%7Ba%2Bc%7D%7Bb%2Bd%7D%20%3C%20%5Cfrac%7Bc%7D%7Bd%7D%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com), e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/751155/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1989104/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/289549/42969.

Comment: And this is the generalization: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/704411/42969

Comment: I suggest to get familiar with the Approach0 math search engine. All your questions so far turned out to be duplicates. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969 for some information about Approach0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $b>0, d>0, bc-ad > 0$.

Your first part is equivalent to proving that

$$b(a+c)-a(b+d)>0.$$

It should be clear from the given conditions that this holds.

Comment: Thank you for the short & precise answer!

Comment: This has been asked and answered many many times.